# Issues installation HermesJMS on OSX

Tags: java, macos, jms, activemq-classic

I am currently having huge issues installing HermesJMS (1.14 or 1.15) on OSX 10.9.2

Downloading the dmg file from their site fails with an error saying the .app file is damaged

So I download the jar file, with the installation being successful.

I downloaded the jar files from here: [1.14](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/files/hermesjms/1.14/)  [1.15](http://hermesjms.com/patches/)

I then switch to the terminal and run the hermes.sh in the bin directory and I get the following error

```
~$ ./hermes.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SplashScreen.create(Unknown Source)
    at hermes.browser.HermesBrowser.main(HermesBrowser.java:224)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to     java.awt.RenderingHints
    at com.jidesoft.swing.JideSwingUtilities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Here are my java versions:

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is so?

I am basically wanting to use it to view a ActiveMQ topic

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: No clue on the Hermes issues (same on my machine).
However, you cannot "view" a topic. There is nothing to view, you can just subscribe from it and have a copy of each message passing through. I wrote a small command line utility for ActiveMQ that you can subscribe to topics with - https://github.com/northlander/a. You can also give ActiveMQ Browser a try if you want something graphical. http://sourceforge.net/projects/activemqbrowser/

Comment: Thanks Petter will give them both a go. Yup I realise I can't view a topic, but with HermesJMS you can subscribe to the topics and view the JMS messages sent to it, which is all I am after. Let me take a look at your command line utility, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Petter, tried installing your cmd utility, a, and get the following errors when trying to install it with maven

OSTML0205036:a ank25$ mvn install
...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.6.0/activemq-all-5.6.0.pom
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.6.0/activemq-all-5.6.0.pom (4 KB at 15.1 KB/sec)
...
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[ERROR] /opt/a/src/main/java/com/libzter/a/A.java:[28,29] error: package org.apache.commons.cli does not exist
...
[INFO] 24 errors
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

Comment: Can't see your error. There is a prepacked release that can be started with java -jar a-..jar  This is perhaps not the correct forum to handle that trouble shooting though.

Comment: Thats fine thanks, probably a problem with my maven repo as I have been build other projects too which depend on internal artefact repos, activemq included. I will try get it to pull the jars locally and see if that works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with Java not enabling web plug-in and Web Start features.  I ran into this problem with Java versions 7 & 8 (jdk1.7.0_21.jdk, jdk1.8.0.jdk).

Java 6 is required.

#### Getting Java 6

- Download and install Java for Mac OS X (1.6.0_65-b14-462): http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572
- Then follow these instructions to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 web plug-in and Web Start features: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202643

#### fyi - Installation locations

These are typical install locations for Java for OSX:

- Apple-installed Java for Mac OS X install location: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
- Oracle Java install location: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home

#### Running HermesJMS with Java 6

To use Java 6 for the life of your terminal window:

```
~$ export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

then run

```
~$ ./hermes.sh
```

Comment: ~$   JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home ./hermes.sh


I need other things to run on other types of Javas

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to "monitor" a JMS Topic within ActiveMQ, you can use [JMSToolBox on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)
You only need a JRE 8 on the path

Answer (score -1):

The first answer did work for me.

The JAVA_HOME variable issue could be fixed by using [jenv](http://www.jenv.be/) utility.

- download Java 1.6 as mentioned above;
- install jenv;
- add Java 1.6 to the list of versions managed by jenv:

jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/

- Add the following lines to hgermesjms.sh file, *# Setup the Java VM* section:

jenv local 1.6

export JAVA_HOME="$HOME/.jenv/versions/`jenv version-name`"

*jenv version-name* should be quoted by backticks (`), Markdown stole them.

- That is how it worked for me.
  The fix is displayed in more details in [this answer](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv/issues/44#issuecomment-39356954).

Comment: I put the information from different sources into one place so that a person who is searching for an answer gets everything in one place and does not have to search more like I had to. Sorry that you do not understand this.