# Running HermesJMS on Mac M1

Tags: java-8, apple-m1, java-6, tibco-ems, hermes-jms

Is it possible to run HermesJMS on modern mac (M1, Ventura 13.4.1)?

When I use Java 1.8 I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.jidesoft.swing.SplashScreen.create(Unknown Source)
    at hermes.browser.HermesBrowser.main(HermesBrowser.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.awt.RenderingHints
    at com.jidesoft.swing.JideSwingUtilities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Also I've installed Java 1.6 based on this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/27696177/2179676 But have another error:

```
2023-06-24 13:22:50.854 java[6627:145885] JavaNativeFoundation: GetGlobalVM: Failed to locate @rpath/libjvm.dylib for JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(). A JVM must be loaded before calling this function.
2023-06-24 13:22:50.854 java[6627:145885] Apple AWT: +[ThreadUtilities getJNIEnvUncached] attempting to attach current thread after JNFObtainEnv() failed
./hermes6.sh: line 207:  6627 Segmentation fault: 11  "$JAVACMD" -XX:NewSize=256m -Xmx1024m $HERMES_OPTS -Dhermes.home=$HERMES_HOME -Dhermes=$HERMES_CFG -Dhermes.libs=$HERMES_LIB_PROPERTY -classpath $LOCALCLASSPATH hermes.browser.HermesBrowser
```

P.S. I know about JMSToolBox but need to have exactly HermesJMS.